# How to change file directory on xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I am trying to change the file directory for XAMPP from htdocs to a different folder. I did go into httpd.conf and change the directory in there like I saw to do from other posts, but it did not work.

When I tried to go to my file from localhost in my browser it would show the folders in the folder, but when I clicked on one, it would say "object not found."

I am unsure of the problem.

Other details:

- Where I want it pointed to is on a VHD
- that VHD is hooked up to sourcetree (idk if this matters)

Thank you in advance

Edit: This is what I changed

```
DocumentRoot "P:/projects"
<Directory "P:/projects">
```

Comment: You **did** restart xampp after you made that change, right?

Comment: @castis this is all I changed: DocumentRoot "P:/projects"
<Directory "P:/projects">      is there more that I should have changed?

Comment: You changed `DocumentRoot "P:/projects"` to `<Directory "P:/projects">`? Those directives do two different things. You may want to start with an apache conf tutorial

Comment: @castis just did that. turns out I did it correctly in the .conf file, the problem is my files are getting the forbidden error and I am unsure of how to get rid of it